# How safe is it to have raw cracked eggs uncovered in the fridge?

Tags: eggs

At my work we crack maybe 400 to 500 eggs as prep in the morning into little cups and put them in the walk-in fridge. I’ve noticed after some hours if I make myself some eggs to eat later in the day I feel really gross and bloated. But if it’s freshly cracked I feel fine! Even if I make the eggs into a sandwich way later that day I’m ok eating them. I can’t find anything on google about it being safe or not uncovered raw cracked eggs in the fridge and how long they last! Would anyone know?

Comment: What job are you doing where you are cracking hundreds of eggs a day but aren't confident that it's safe to do so?

Answer (score 6):

The main risk to cracked eggs in a fridge is contamination, either by other food or by things like mould spores in the air. **Assuming that the fridge and the containers you are using are clean, there are no food safety issues with leaving them out of their shells in the fridge for a few hours.** (See e.g. [this US guidance](https://www.foodsafety.gov/food-safety-charts/cold-food-storage-charts) which suggests 2–4 days.)

The feelings you are having are most likely caused by your own expectations, or otherwise something else about the situation (perhaps when you have eggs later in the day you are more likely to be hungry already, or too full, or whatever) or a coincidence.

However, assuming that you are cracking hundreds of eggs a day because you are working to make food for people, I would encourage you to educate yourself more about food safety guidance – not just to protect yourself legally but also for your own peace of mind and to protect the health of your customers.